# Bash script: how to stop looping after a match was found?

Tags: regex, bash, loops

This must be very basic but I can't not find a way to solve it.

I have a script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

seqFolder="/raw_data/data"

seqmode="paired"

Input=$(basename ${seqFolder});

if [ $seqmode = paired ]; then

    for x in $seqFolder/*; do
        if [[ "$x" =~ .*\.fastq.gz$ ]]; then
            z=$(basename $x 1_001.fastq.gz)

            echo $z
            echo "file of this iteration $z"1_001.fastq.gz" $z"2_001.fastq.gz""
        fi
    done
fi
```

When I run this script I get this:

```
MG-AB-17_S17_R
file of this iteration MG-AB-17_S17_R1_001.fastq.gz MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz
file of this iteration MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz1_001.fastq.gz MG-    AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz2_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-81_S74_R
file of this iteration MG-AB-81_S74_R1_001.fastq.gz MG-AB-81_S74_R2_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-81_S74_R2_001.fastq.gz
file of this iteration MG-AB-81_S74_R2_001.fastq.gz1_001.fastq.gz MG-  AB-81_S74_R2_001.fastq.gz2_001.fastq.gz
```

Files in: /raw_data/data are these 4 (this is just example):

```
MG-AB-17_S17_R1_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-81_S74_R1_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-81_S74_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

The issue is that I don't want my variable `$z` to be `MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz` or `MG-AB-81_S74_R2_001.fastq.gz` because files like these:

```
MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz1_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz2_001.fastq.gz 
...
```

don't exist in directory `/raw_data/data`

I was thinking that `.fastq.gz$` in `"$x" =~ .*\.fastq.gz$` would ensure that, but it seems that's not the case. Can you please advise.

Comment: All your filenames match the regexp `.*\.fastq.gz$`. How is that check supposed to exclude those files?

Comment: I only want to match/parse/process these 4 files: MG-AB-17_S17_R1_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-81_S74_R1_001.fastq.gz
MG-AB-81_S74_R2_001.fastq.gz. the issue is that my script (which is bugged) invents new files, like: MG-AB-17_S17_R2_001.fastq.gz1_001.fastq.gz

Comment: The problem is that you're removing the suffix `1_001.fastq.gz`. But the files that have `R2` don't have that suffix, so `basename` doesn't remove the suffix.

Comment: how is the title related to the body of your post?

Comment: Within a loop, you can add an `if` statement.  When the check is true, call `break` to exit the loop right there and then.

Comment: @umläute can you please tell me what would be better title?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `break` statement.

```
$ cat /tmp/so3651.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo "i: $i"
    if [[ -f /tmp/foo$i ]]; then
        echo "found it!"
        break
    fi
done
```

If the file doesn't exist, it produces:

```
$ /tmp/so3651.sh
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
i: 5
```

But when a file does exist, it stops early:

```
$ touch /tmp/foo4
$ /tmp/so3651.sh
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
found it!
```